# Git aliases error in .gitconfig file

Tags: git, alias

I've been using this alias:

```
aliases = !git config --get-regexp 'alias.*' | colrm 1 6 | sed 's/[ ]/ = /'
```

to show all aliases in the config file.

but it's messy - I wanted to add a color to the alias name, before the "=" sign.
So I added some color:

```
aliases = !git config --get-regexp 'alias.*' | colrm 1 6 | sed 's/[ ]/ = /' | awk '{printf "\033[1;31m" $1 "\033[0m"; $1=""; print $0;}'
```

it works great when I use the command from the CLI, but when I try to put it in the .gitconfig file it throws an error. something to do with the quotation marks.
I tried to escape them, but to no avail...

**How can I get the alias to work?**

Comment: You need to see how your quotes have been preserved (or removed) in the `gitconfig` file (local, or global, depending on how you add your alias). if a simple quote disappear, you need to have in input `'\''`.

Comment: Actually, I don't use the config command, but paste it as-is in the .gitconfig file. The way I posted is the way it's shown in the file...I do know, though, that the problem is with the double-quotes, and no matter how I tried to escape them it didn't work...

Comment: ok, I face similar issue with your alias in my msysgit1.7.6 (Windows) distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave it a try and it works by just quoting the whole string:

```
alias2 = !"git config --get-regexp 'alias.*' | colrm 1 6 | sed 's/[ ]/ = /'"
```

You can have a great help to debug your config by using trace like that:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git alias2
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some quoting problems. I suggest a dedicated shell script because quoting makes it quite unreadable. With less separate processes:

git-color-aliases

```
#!/bin/sh
git config --get-regexp 'alias.*' | awk '{printf "\033[1;31m%s\033[0m = ", substr($1,7); $1=""; print $0}'
```

.gitconfig

```
aliases = color-aliases
```